# How to Program the Kendo pdfExport event to export parent and child rows

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I am using kendo v 2016.3.914
I have a grid that has a single grouping that shows 10 parent rows with all  child rows collapsed.
When my users click the out of the box export to excel button, only the parent rows are exported.
So in my Javascript I added the pdfExport method and when the users click the "export to pdf" button, it expands all the rows (I see this happening by using the F12 Developer Tools), but still the export only exports the top group.

What do I have to do to get the 'Export to PDF' to export all rows?

Answer (score 0):

you must first expand all the rows first and then the export will export all rows.